Exhausting sequences contain a $\pi$ lift of a subset with a $(1-\delta)$ factor
Let $\pi : Y \to X$ be a measurable map between the $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $(Y, \mathcal{B}, \nu)$ and $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$. Suppose there exists $c \in (0, \infty)$ such that for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$,
$$
\nu \circ \pi^{-1}(A) = c \mu(A).
$$
Additionally, let $B \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $0 < \mu(B) < \infty$, and let $B_n \in \mathcal{B}$ for $n \geq 1$ satisfy
$$
\pi^{-1}(B) \cap B_n \to \pi^{-1}(B) \quad (\text{mod } \nu) \quad \text{as } n \to \infty.
$$
I want to prove that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\delta \in (0, 1)$, there exists some $m \geq 1$ and a set $Z \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $Z \subseteq B$ and $\mu(B \setminus Z) < \varepsilon$, for which the following holds for any $E \in \mathcal{A}$:
$$
\nu\left( (\pi^{-1}(Z) \cap B_m) \cap \pi^{-1}(Z \cap E) \right) \ge (1-\delta) \cdot c \mu(Z \cap E).
$$
My approach:
Let us choose $Z \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu(Z) > 0$ and $\mu(B \setminus Z) < \varepsilon$. Since
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \nu(\pi^{-1}(B) \cap B_n) = \nu(\pi^{-1}(B)),
$$
it follows that the sequence $B_n$ approximates $\pi^{-1}(B)$ in the sense that the measure of the difference $\pi^{-1}(B) \setminus B_n$ under $\nu$ goes to zero as $n$ increases. Thus, $B_n$ "converges" to $\pi^{-1}(B)$ in the sense of measure $\nu$.
Then there exists $m \geq 1$ such that
$$
\nu\left(\pi^{-1}(B) \setminus \left(\pi^{-1}(B) \cap B_m\right)\right) < \varepsilon \cdot c \mu(Z).
$$
Now, for $E \in \mathcal{A}$, we have:
$$
\nu\left( (\pi^{-1}(Z) \cap B_m) \cap \pi^{-1}(Z \cap E) \right) = \nu\left( \pi^{-1}(Z \cap E) \cap B_m \right).
$$
Using the fact that $\nu \circ \pi^{-1}(A) = c \mu(A)$, this becomes:
$$
c \mu(Z \cap E) - \nu\left( \pi^{-1}(Z \cap E) \setminus B_m \right).
$$
So I want to show that
\begin{align*}c \mu(Z \cap E) - \nu\left( \pi^{-1}(Z \cap E) \setminus B_m \right)&\ge (1-\delta) \cdot c \mu(Z \cap E)\\
\text{That is, } \hspace{85pt} \delta \cdot c \mu(Z \cap E)&\ge \nu\left( \pi^{-1}(Z \cap E) \setminus B_m \right).
\end{align*}
However, I am unsure how to proceed from here. Could you kindly help me to complete this argument? Thank you for your time and assistance.
